# This simple little "Select" statement.....why doesn't it work?

Tags: php, mysql, select

Assume that the database connection is good, the table name and column name are correct, and that there is actually a row in the database with the value "advoom.com" in it. What keeps this from working? I get the error "Unknown column 'advoom.com' in 'where clause'"

I've also tried putting the variable outside the quotes and using "." to concatenate the command.  Same error.

This is a snippet of a PHP page written in Dreamweaver.

$pageURL = "advoom.com";

```
mysql_select_db($database_bizCon, $bizCon);

$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM buttonprefsNEW WHERE curl = $pageURL";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $bizCon) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround a string with quotes in sql.

```
$pageURL = "advoom.com";
mysql_select_db($database_bizCon, $bizCon);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `buttonprefsNEW` WHERE `curl` = '".$pageURL."'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $bizCon) or die(mysql_error());
```

And don't forget to escape your input if needed.

Answer (score 13):

Use this:

```
mysql_select_db($database_bizCon, $bizCon);

$pageURL = mysql_real_escape_string($pageURL);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM buttonprefsNEW WHERE curl = '" . $pageURL . "'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $bizCon) or die(mysql_error());
```

You simply need the single quotes in this case to match it.

The string `$pageURL` will be use as a column in this case and not a string. So you want to select all the rows where the column `advoom.com` equal to the column `curl`. Now, the column `advoom.com` does not exists, this is why you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Single Quote` *before* and *after* the variable. The simpliest solution without concactenation in PHP

```
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM buttonprefsNEW WHERE curl = '$pageURL'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$url = "http://example.com";
mysql_select_db($database_bizCon, $bizCon);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `buttonprefsNEW` WHERE `curl` = '".$url ."'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $bizCon) or die(mysql_error());
```